# How can I fill in a numeric variable with specific numbers, based on the levels of a factorial variable in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
df<-data.frame(month = c("Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Mar", "Apr", 
                         "May", "Jun", "Jul"), 
               height = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

and I have specific numbers (means for each month) which I have calculated myself: height in March should be 2.165, in April should be 3.135, May 2.981, June 3.279, July 3.154. I'm just wondering how I would use if or ifelse in this to fill in my height column? Sorry I know this is basic, but I can't find the answer on here anywhere and I'm really stuck!

Comment: How do you know which values to go to which month? Or do you just assume the height vector contains the values for MARCH, APRIL, MAY in that order?

Comment: I calculated mean heights for each month separately so I know which numbers should go with which month, I just want to fill the column in on R without having to go back to excel and do it manually and re-read the data in. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: then if you have the height vector, do `df$height <- height`

Comment: My actual dataset has each month 30 times, and the dataset I used to calculate the means for height has 30 entries for each month, so I can't put them together in one dataframe as they dont fit?

Comment: Then probably you should consider rephrasing your question. No one understands what you have and what you want. You should consider asking the question in this format 1) Example of data you have 2)  Give the expected output 3) Explain the expected output

Comment: The person below understood my question. Thanks for your comments anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can index into a named vector by name.

```
height_key <- c(Mar = 2.165, Apr = 3.135, May = 2.981, Jun = 3.279, Jul = 3.154)

df$height <- height_key[df$month]

> df
   month height
1    Mar  2.165
2    Apr  3.135
3    May  2.981
4    Jun  3.279
5    Jul  3.154
6    Mar  2.165
7    Apr  3.135
8    May  2.981
9    Jun  3.279
10   Jul  3.154
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That's perfect :)